# how to send django formset data with ajax?

Tags: javascript, python, django, ajax, django-forms

first I want get data from form and then send this data to server with ajax...

```
<script>
    document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
        const data = Object.formEntries(new FormData(e.target).entries());
        console.log(data);
        SubmitButtonClicked();
    });
</script>

<script>
    function SubmitButtonClicked(){
        $.ajax({
            dataType:"json",
            type:"POST",
            url:"{% url 'meraj_public:new_rrr' %}",
            data: {
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: "{{ csrf_token }}",
                data: data,
            },

            success: function(response){
                let success = response.success;
                if (succes === false){
                    alert('error');
                }else{
                    alert('success')
                }
            }
        })
    }
</script>
```

but here, data not diplay on console and there was an error:
`Uncaught ReferenceError SubmitButtonClicked is not defined`

my first question is:
How to get all form data?

and then:
How to send data to the view and check validation of data in order that show error or save data?